# HTTP connection pools to share among processes

Tags: http, nginx, proxy, amazon-s3

Where I work our main web application is served with nginx+uwsgi+Django. A given production box has 80 uwsgi worker processes running on it. Our Django application makes moderately frequent requests to Amazon S3 but, if each of those 80 workers has to use its own HTTP connection for such requests, they're not frequent enough to take advantage of the (relatively short) HTTP Keep-Alive allowed for by Amazon's servers. So, we frequently have to pay a reconnection penalty after the connection is dropped on Amazon's side.

What I would like is if there were a proxy service running on the same box that could "concentrate" the S3 connections from those 80 processes down into a smaller pool of HTTP connections that would get enough use that they would be kept alive. The Django app would connect to the proxy, and the proxy would use its pool of kept-alive connections to forward the requests to S3. I see that it is possible to use nginx itself as a forward proxy, but it's not clear to me if or how this can take advantage of connection pooling the way I have in mind. An ideal solution would be good at auto-scaling so that a uwsgi worker would never have to wait on the proxy itself for a connection, but would pare back connections as load drops so as to keep the connections as "hot" as possible (perhaps keeping 1 or 2 spare to handle occasional upticks).

I've run across other forward proxies such as Squid but these products seem designed to fulfill the more traditional caching proxy role for use by e.g. ISPs that have many disparate remote clients.

Does anyone know of an existing solution for this type of problem? Many thanks!